# Add ellipsis replacement to Pathauto

Tags: 7, path-aliases

To handle users who like to occasionally use the custom ellipsis character from MS Word in titles, I would like to add replacement options for the character in the Punctuation settings for [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) using hook_pathauto_punctuation_chars_alter(). The problem is determining what value to put in the value setting in the hook. I found the T_ELLIPSIS constant in tokenizer.php, and tried using it like so:

```
function my_module_pathauto_punctuation_chars_alter(array &$punctuation) {
  $punctuation['ellipsis'] = array(
    'value' => T_ELLIPSIS,
    'name' => t('')
  );
}
```

and the value shows as `Ellipsis (389)` for the field label in the settings. However, when the alias is generated with the ellipsis character in the node title, it doesn't get replaced.

Is there a better/easier way to handle this? Also, should I use something like the UTF-8 code instead of the constant?

Answer (score 0):

My prefered solution to scrub out extraneous characters in Pathauto URLs is this option under **Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases » Settings**.

[image]

It will scrub out all the extraneous characters that can mess up browsers/crawlers. This is assuming you're on an English language website.